# Does downloading a ROM put me in legal trouble?

Tags: united-states

I am misled on the legal doctrine for ROMs. I am aware that I am using the word ROM, not emulator, because I am aware of the difference. My research has shown that one for sure way of being in legal trouble is by downloading a ROM from a site or by hosting such content, but I am confused if I fall into this case. This is due to conflicting information.

I am a 24-year-old Caucasian male residing in California, where United States law applies. I do not wish to host ROMs, but I am researching about how to stay within the law and play video games. I wish to play Wipeout: The Game because I feel nostalgic for it, using the Dolphin emulator. I do own a copy of the game on the Wii, and I would like to know how can I play my game legally, regardless of if my save data is there or not. The game is available for purchase currently by Activision, and was released in 2010. The game contains content from American Broadcasting Company, who has rights to the Wipeout property. The Wipeout TV series ended in 2014. I do not wish to stream or publish gameplay of the game, and instead play it by myself.

Please cite sources if you are willing to answer my question. I cannot take your word for it. Also, before I am marked as a duplicate, I have a special case not mentioned in the other questions.